# Getting error "Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'" when using BedrockChat in langchainjs

Tags: langchain, langchain-js

```
import { BedrockChat } from "@langchain/community/chat_models/bedrock";
import { HumanMessage } from "@langchain/core/messages";
const model = new BedrockChat({
      model: "meta.llama2-13b-chat-v1",
      region: "us-east-1",
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: `${process.env.ACCESS_KEY}`,
        secretAccessKey: `${process.env.SECRET_KEY}`,
      },
    });
    const res = await model.invoke([
      new HumanMessage({ content: "Tell me a joke" }),
    ]);
    console.log(res);
```

> I am getting the below error on running the above code
>
> Server Error
> **Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found**
>
> Import trace for requested module:
> ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-process/dist-es/fromProcess.js
> ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-process/dist-es/index.js
> ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/dist-es/defaultProvider.js
> ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/dist-es/index.js
> ./node_modules/@langchain/community/dist/chat_models/bedrock/index.js
> ./node_modules/@langchain/community/chat_models/bedrock.js
> ./app/api/chat/retrieval/route.ts
> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-edge-app-route-loader/index.js?